# Write File then Read File works OK once, then hangs after with HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm writing an app for Windows Phone 8. I have two methods in a FileManager class. One reads, and the other writes.

1. (Over)write a File in Page1.xaml
2. Navigate to Page2.xaml
3. Read a File in Page2.xaml
4. Hit the physical back button to go to Page1.xaml
5. Edit the File in Page1.xaml
6. (Over)write a File in Page1.xaml
7. Navigate to Page2.xaml
8. Read a File in Page2.xaml

I can run through steps 1-5 without issue, but when I get to step 6 the application hangs - and I get the following error:

Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

EDIT - Here's the code:

I'm using AsyncLock and AsyncSemaphore from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/12/10266988.aspx

In the Page1.xaml.cs:

```
    private void appBarButtonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        save().Wait();
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page2.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }

    private Task save()
    {
        FileManager fileManager = new FileManager();
        return fileManager.WriteToFile("TestFolder", "TestFile.html", "contents as a string");
    }
```

In Page2.xaml.cs

```
    public Preview()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Load the Preview
        loadContents();

        // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
        BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();

    }

    private async void loadContents()
    {
        FileManager fileManager = new FileManager();
        String strOutput = await fileManager.ReadFromFile("TestFolder", "TestFile.html");
        previewBrowser.NavigateToString(strOutput);
    }
```

FileManager.cs looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Storage;

namespace MyApp
{
    class FileManager
    {
        StorageFolder local;
        private static readonly AsyncLock m_lock = new AsyncLock();

        public FileManager()
        {
            // Get the local folder
            local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        }

        public async Task WriteToFile(String FolderName, String FileName, String contents)
        {
            using (await m_lock.LockAsync())
            {
                // Get the byte array data in String contents 
                byte[] fileBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(contents.ToCharArray());

                // Create a new folder name, or open it, if it already exists
                var dataFolder = await local.CreateFolderAsync(FolderName.ToString(),
                    CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

                // Create a new file, or overwrite it's contents if it already exists
                var file = await dataFolder.CreateFileAsync(FileName.ToString(),
                    CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

                // Write the data in contents
                using (var s = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
                {
                    s.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
                }
            }
        }

        public async Task<String> ReadFromFile(String FolderName, String FileName)
        {
            using (await m_lock.LockAsync())
            {
                if (local != null)
                {
                    // Get the DataFolder folder
                    var dataFolder = await local.GetFolderAsync(FolderName.ToString());

                    // Get the file
                    var file = await dataFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync(FileName.ToString());

                    // Read the data
                    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(file))
                    {
                        return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }a
    }
}
```

Comment: Code, we need the code.. At least of step 6

Comment: Probably a problem with your code. By the way, where is your code?

Comment: @BlackBear does that code help?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `using` (or properly closing files) somewhere.

Comment: @alexmcroberts - this was posted before any code was in the question... Even with code I think it still may be valid - there are some `IDisposable` objects your are not `Dispose`/`using` (like `file`, also it may be disposed by StreamReader).

Comment: could you give an example of how I should do this?